# Dynamically adding properties to a translatable Django model

Tags: python, django, properties, model

So I want to add properties to a model resembling the attributes of another model, that holds translatable fields.

My models:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ... fields ...

class MyModelTranslation(models.Model):
    ... the fields I want on MyModel ...
    name = models.CharField()
    city = models.CharField()
    language = models.CharField()
    mymodel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
```

So I wrote following `__init__`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # get_translation gets the object, that holds the translation fields for the
        # current active language
        trans = lambda c: c.get_translation()

        setattr(self.__class__, 'translation', property(trans))

        fget = lambda c: getattr(trans(c), 'name')
        fset = lambda c, v: setattr(trans(c), 'name', v)
        setattr(self.__class__, 'name', property(fget, fset))

        fget = lambda c: getattr(trans(c), 'city')
        fset = lambda c, v: setattr(trans(c), 'city', v)
        setattr(self.__class__, 'city', property(fget, fset))
```

This works perfectly. When I then call `mymodel.name`, I get the `mymodeltranslation.name` for the active language. Setting this value is also possible.

Since I want to have this being made dynamically so I can use it in a mixin, I added it to a for loop, like so:

```
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        trans = lambda c: c.get_translation()
        setattr(self.__class__, 'translation', property(trans))

        # returns all fields of the translation model
        trans_fields = [field.name for field in [
            related for related in self._meta.get_all_related_objects()
            if "translation" in related.name
        ][0].model._meta.fields]

        # should then assign all those fields dynamically
        for name in trans_fields:
            if not name == 'id' and not name == 'mymodel':
                fget = lambda c: getattr(trans(c), name)
                fset = lambda c, v: setattr(trans(c), name, v)
                setattr(self.__class__, name, property(fget, fset))
```

So I thought, okay, since the `name` value resembles the name of the field, that I used to add manually before, it should then add a `property` with a name of the value of `name` on each run of the for loop.
But it does not. When I call `mymodel.name` it returns the model instance (so basically `self`). I have no clue, what is different, when I do it in a forloop instead of all manually.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use something like django-transmeta.... There are some apps about this problem